# Set multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I have string 
`$s = 'controller/front/home';`

value
`$v = "some value";`

and array
`$a = [];`

What is the best way to make multidimensional array like that?

`$a['controller']['front']['home'] = $v;`

[edit]

I don't know how many parts (separated by /) string $s can have, so manual array building by exploded parts is the last option I would consider.

Comment: what you actually trying to do? Show your code efforts also....

Comment: `$a = $v; foreach (array_reverse(explode('/', $s)) as $i) $a = array($i => $a);`

Comment: This question has the same topic with you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627252/php-make-multi-dimensional-associative-array-from-a-delimited-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this after a small research:

- [PHP dynamic array path access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201804/php-dynamic-array-path-access)

By this article, I've adapted it to following

```
$path = 'controller/front/home';
$value = 'some value';

$parts = explode('/', $path);

$arrayPath = [];

$temp = &$arrayPath;
foreach($parts as $part) {
    if(!isset($temp[$part])) {
        $temp[$part] = [];
    }
    $temp = &$temp[$part];
}
$temp = $value;

var_dump($arrayPath);
```

Prints:

```
array (size=1)
  'controller' => 
    array (size=1)
      'front' => 
        array (size=1)
          'home' => string 'some value' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = $v; foreach (array_reverse(explode('/', $s)) as $i) $a = array($i => $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
   $array = explode('/', $s);
```

and then :

```
  $a[$array[0]][$array[1]][$array[2]] = $v;
```